# Laravel Dusk Draw on Canvas Element

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-dusk

I am trying to make a [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk#using-the-mouse) test to sign a `canvas` elememt (jSignature plugin)

But can seem to get it working. this is my current code:

```
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $browser->visit('/form')

            # Sign
            ->click('#input-13')
            ->pause(3000)
            ->mouseover('.jSignature')
            ->click('.jSignature')
            ->moveByOffset(100,100)
    });
```

Any ideas how?

Comment: My assumption is; it click then move the mouse. It doesn't do a long press. Maybe you could try with `$browser->dragDown('.jSignature', 100);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it! that's how I did it (the signature opens in a bootstrap modal window):

```
            ->click('#input-13')
            ->pause(3000)
            ->mouseover('.jSignature')
            ->click('.jSignature')
            ->dragRight('.jSignature',100)
            ->dragLeft('.jSignature',200)
            ->pause(3000);
```

The pausing is there to allow bootstrap's transitions to end.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone's trying to draw onto a canvas using clicking points like on a map, you can use `clickAndHold()` then `releaseMouse()` to emulate an actual click

```
$browser->click('#map')
        ->clickAndHold()
        ->releaseMouse()
        ->moveMouse(0, 200)
        ->clickAndHold()
        ->releaseMouse()
        ->moveMouse(200, 0)
        ->clickAndHold()
        ->releaseMouse()
        ->moveMouse(0, -200)
        ->clickAndHold()
        ->releaseMouse()
        ->moveMouse(-200, 0)
        ->screenshot('1');
```